# Question about map induced by Ext

Tags: homological-algebra

I didn't quite understand some definitions on some homology topics. Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A, A', C$ $R$-modules, consider the map $f^*: Ext^1_R(C,A) \rightarrow Ext^1_R(C,A') $ induced by $f : A \rightarrow A'$ how is the map  defined? In what sense is the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow0$ an element of $Im f^*$?

Comment: It's probably easier to define using Hom and projective resolutions.

Comment: Consider the pushout $B'=A'\coprod_A B$ and show that $0\to A'\to B'\to C\to 0$ is a short exact sequence. This give an extension in $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(C,A')$ which is the image by $f^*$ of the extension given by the initial short exact sequence.